# Using Swagger for Spring Boot API Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have an API that accepts a multi part form data (json body and file upload).  My API works when I use Postman but Swagger does not seem to like it.  Is there a way to allow for multipart payload?  I know I can accepts the json body as a binary file upload, but I would prefer to allow the user to enter the json body into a text area in Swagger.  Here is my example code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/myPost", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MyResult> createPost(
      @RequestPart(value = "body", required = true) MyDTO myDto,
      @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile[] attachments) {
   //my code
}
```

Swagger will then show a Text area called Body, which has my MyDTO schema and file attachment form.  When I submit, I get this error in my Spring Boot API:

**org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported**

I can change the RequestParts to this:

```
@RequestPart(value = "body") @Parameter(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary")) final MyDTO myDTO ,
@RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) final MultipartFile[] attachments
```

And this will work, but instead of having a Body text area, which displays the MyDTO Schema, Swagger just shows two file upload forms (the Body upload works by putting the JSON payload into a json file and uploading that).  While it will work, it is an inconvenience to the user, as they can't just copy in the json payload and instead have to create a separate json file. Is there a way to allow a multip part form to have both a json payload and a file attachment?

thanks